# Googlebot tries to access links from another unavailable website

Tags: nginx, googlebot

I'm getting a bit paranoid because there's been a small breach on my web server recently and that linked to this I found multiple logs like this from nginx:

> `access.log-20220602:66.249.70.69 - - [01/Jun/2022:23:14:59 +0200] "GET /weird/path/ HTTP/1.1" 404 153 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)" "-"`

Where /weird/path is basically a path to a blog article I had on a blog from like 14 years ago. It was WordPress like the current one but the domain names are completely different. Think `blabla.isp.example/blog` vs. `blog.whatever.example`. The  paths crawled USED to exist and can still be seen in the Wayback machine.

How is this possible? That IP seems to be a legit Googlebot.

Comment: What makes you think that Googlebot is finding links on the Wayback machine rather than just remembering the URLs from 14 years ago itself?

Comment: That's besides the point. The two domains are completely different; what I don't get is that Googlebot "associates" them like this.

Comment: Has there ever been a redirect from the old domain to the new one? Presumably there's no WhoIs information linking the two domains? (A long time ago... I had some free ISP provided webspace on a subdomain of an ISPs domain. When I terminated my account at the ISP they "magically" implemented an external redirect to my actual domain, which happened to be quite similar to the subdomain and was the domain I was using in emails. This redirect actually stayed in place for some considerable time.)

Comment: Might just be related to google core update ... https://www.seroundtable.com/google-may-2022-broad-core-update-seo-impact-33512.html ... lots of volatility on which sites are showing up on the first page as well.

Comment: If they return 404 they will be removed again. Google remembers 404s because sometimes they come back to life, (sometimes the removal was because the server was down) ... they are just checking.

Comment: @MrWhite There was never any redirect no. No WHOIS info linking the two either.

Comment: @Wayne I see, could be. I know there's been heaps of progress in AI but this still boggles my mind and really made me think my server was being attacked by someone with knowledge of very old websites of mine...